# Dropdown on icon, bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap (I have bootstrap and jquery included and dropdowns working elsewhere) and tryingo to use my profile icon as a trigger for a dropdown with an option to logout.

My profile icon is showing the downward caret like it's a dropdown, but when I click there is no dropdown triggered.

I can't use a button here, it needs to be tied to the icon.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="menu-button profile dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        <i class="far fa-user-circle fa-2x"></i>
    </div>

   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li>Logout</li>
   </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work: https://www.codeply.com/go/Gye6PGNDTm

Comment: my files included in my local site are: ```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>``` do you see an issue with that?

Comment: You need popper.js too

Comment: That's not included on the codeply though? I need that just for the bootstrap dropdown?

Comment: Seems to not be working even with popper installed